# Как сделать php цикл в БД c добавлением значений из Excel?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, phpexcel

подскажите как зациклить такую операцию с добавлением значений в базу данных?
Есть файл Excel собирающий значения с других файлов. Он содержит 4 столбца где в столбце: A-номер, B-показатель1, С-показатель2, D-показатель3. Доступ ко всем параметрам получаю через `getCalculatedValue()`
В столбце будет более 200 значений. Как получить значения из строки понятно, делаю так:

```
$file = 'Result.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file); 
$project_number = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('A1')->getValue();
$par1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('B1')->getCalculatedValue();
$par2 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('C1')->getCalculatedValue();
$par3 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCell('D1')->getCalculatedValue();
```

И далее делаю запрос на вставку всех параметров(par1 par2 par3 в столбцы базы данных, если номер в бд равен номеру в столбце A

```
$sql = "UPDATE project_registry SET green_points = '$par1', yellow_points = '$par2', red_points = '$par3'
WHERE project_number = '$project_number'";

$result_set = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: А что за ошибка падает? И разве при определении $sql - не нужна конкатенация строк, типа "UPDATE project_registry SET green_points = '.$par1.', yellow_points = '.$par2.', red_points = '.$par3.'
WHERE project_number = '.$project_number'."?

Comment: в таком виде, в котором выше запрос написан, у меся все отрабатывает.
Насчет ошибки, ошибки нет, просто я не понимаю до конца как это зациклить

Comment: Точнее я понимаю что мне нужно использовать цикл foreach, и каким-то образом проверять значение в ячейке, но не понимаю как к ней обратиться
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0);
foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)    {
      $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            echo $value;
        }
}

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Documentation/Examples/Reader/exampleReader10.php. Там вроде как раз описано то что вам надо. На выходе получится массив по которому обычными средствами можно пробежаться foreach

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за подсказки, решил вопрос следующим путем.

Сформировал многомерный массив по паре ключ => строка со значениями A,B,C,D

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$array_data = array();
foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row){
    $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex ();
    $array_data[$rowIndex] = array('A'=>'', 'B'=>'','C'=>'','D'=>'');

    $cell = $sheet->getCell('A' . $rowIndex);
    $array_data[$rowIndex]['A'] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    $cell = $sheet->getCell('B' . $rowIndex);
    $array_data[$rowIndex]['B'] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    $cell = $sheet->getCell('C' . $rowIndex);
    $array_data[$rowIndex]['C'] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    $cell = $sheet->getCell('D' . $rowIndex);
    $array_data[$rowIndex]['D'] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
}
```

На выводе `print_r($array_data[1])` получил строку со значениями в ячейках (A1:D1);

Далее собрал в цикл:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($array_data); $i++) {
     $sql = "UPDATE project_registry SET green_points =".$array_data[$i]['B'].", yellow_points = ".$array_data[$i]['C'].", red_points = ".$array_data[$i]['D']." WHERE project_number = ".$array_data[$i]['A']." ";
     $result_set = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);  
      print_r($sql);
}
```